# Encoding recursive tree-creation with while loop + stacks

Tags: scala

I'm a bit embarassed to admit this, but I seem to be pretty stumped by what should be a simple programming problem. I'm building a decision tree implementation, and have been using recursion to take a list of labeled samples, recursively split the list in half, and turn it into a tree.

Unfortunately, with deep trees I run into stack overflow errors (ha!), so my first thought was to use continuations to turn it into tail recursion. Unfortunately Scala doesn't support that kind of TCO, so the only solution is to use a trampoline. A trampoline seems kinda inefficient and I was hoping there would be some simple stack-based imperative solution to this problem, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding it.

The recursive version looks sort of like (simplified):

```
private def trainTree(samples: Seq[Sample], usedFeatures: Set[Int]): DTree = {
  if (shouldStop(samples)) {
    DTLeaf(makeProportions(samples))
  } else {
    val featureIdx = getSplittingFeature(samples, usedFeatures)
    val (statsWithFeature, statsWithoutFeature) = samples.partition(hasFeature(featureIdx, _))
    DTBranch(
      trainTree(statsWithFeature, usedFeatures + featureIdx), 
      trainTree(statsWithoutFeature, usedFeatures + featureIdx),
      featureIdx)
  }
}
```

So basically I'm recursively subdividing the list into two according to some feature of the data, and passing through a list of used features so I don't repeat - that's all handled in the "getSplittingFeature" function so we can ignore it. The code is really simple! Still, I'm having trouble figuring out a stack-based solution that doesn't just use closures and effectively become a trampoline. I know we'll at least have to keep around little "frames" of arguments in the stack but I would like to avoid closure calls.

I get that I should be writing out explicitly what the callstack and program counter handle for me implicitly in the recursive solution, but I'm having trouble doing that without continuations. At this point it's hardly even about efficiency, I'm just curious. So please, no need to remind me that premature optimization is the root of all evil and the trampoline-based solution will probably work just fine. I know it probably will - this is basically a puzzle for it's own sake.

Can anyone tell me what the canonical while-loop-and-stack-based solution to this sort of thing is?

UPDATE: Based on Thipor Kong's excellent solution, I've coded up a while-loops/stacks/hashtable based implementation of the algorithm that should be a direct translation of the recursive version. This is exactly what I was looking for:

FINAL UPDATE: I've used sequential integer indices, as well as putting everything back into arrays instead of maps for performance, added maxDepth support, and finally have a solution with the same performance as the recursive version (not sure about memory usage but I would guess less):

```
private def trainTreeNoMaxDepth(startingSamples: Seq[Sample], startingMaxDepth: Int): DTree = {
  // Use arraybuffer as dense mutable int-indexed map - no IndexOutOfBoundsException, just expand to fit
  type DenseIntMap[T] = ArrayBuffer[T]
  def updateIntMap[@specialized T](ab: DenseIntMap[T], idx: Int, item: T, dfault: T = null.asInstanceOf[T]) = {
    if (ab.length <= idx) {ab.insertAll(ab.length, Iterable.fill(idx - ab.length + 1)(dfault)) }
    ab.update(idx, item)
  }
  var currentChildId = 0 // get childIdx or create one if it's not there already
  def child(childMap: DenseIntMap[Int], heapIdx: Int) =
    if (childMap.length > heapIdx && childMap(heapIdx) != -1) childMap(heapIdx)
    else {currentChildId += 1; updateIntMap(childMap, heapIdx, currentChildId, -1); currentChildId }
  // go down
  val leftChildren, rightChildren = new DenseIntMap[Int]() // heapIdx -> childHeapIdx
  val todo = Stack((startingSamples, Set.empty[Int], startingMaxDepth, 0)) // samples, usedFeatures, maxDepth, heapIdx
  val branches = new Stack[(Int, Int)]() // heapIdx, featureIdx
  val nodes = new DenseIntMap[DTree]() // heapIdx -> node
  while (!todo.isEmpty) {
    val (samples, usedFeatures, maxDepth, heapIdx) = todo.pop()
    if (shouldStop(samples) || maxDepth == 0) {
      updateIntMap(nodes, heapIdx, DTLeaf(makeProportions(samples)))
    } else {
      val featureIdx = getSplittingFeature(samples, usedFeatures)
      val (statsWithFeature, statsWithoutFeature) = samples.partition(hasFeature(featureIdx, _))
      todo.push((statsWithFeature, usedFeatures + featureIdx, maxDepth - 1, child(leftChildren, heapIdx)))
      todo.push((statsWithoutFeature, usedFeatures + featureIdx, maxDepth - 1, child(rightChildren, heapIdx)))
      branches.push((heapIdx, featureIdx))
    }
  }
  // go up
  while (!branches.isEmpty) {
    val (heapIdx, featureIdx) = branches.pop()
    updateIntMap(nodes, heapIdx, DTBranch(nodes(child(leftChildren, heapIdx)), nodes(child(rightChildren, heapIdx)), featureIdx))
  }
  nodes(0)
}
```

Comment: Isn't offloading to a stack-based implementation (where the stack is on the heap) conceptually the same as trampolining?

Comment: Sort of, but trampolining means you are keeping a stack full of closures, where I'm hoping that there's a solution that only uses a stack full of data. Maybe labeled data like StepOne(a,b,c), StepTwo(a,b,c) or multiple stacks or something, but no function calls would be involved.

Comment: Made another change to my code. The name space of node ids is used more economically and you can plugin you own type of the node ids (or BigInt, if you like).

Comment: Of course, I ignore everything of your application. But working currently with decision trees, I am a bit surprised by the StackOverflow. It certainly means that your tree is really unbalanced. It is often an hint for over-training. You should prevent expension of the tree, when the number of instances in a leaf will be to small to make any sense.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. A stackoverflow in a decisiontree means you have almost certainly messed up. Still, it's nice to have the option to handle arbitrary depths - the way my code reads is basically if (maxDepth < 1000) buildTreeRecursive() else buildTreeImperative()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the binary tree in an array, as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees): For node `i`, the left child goes into `2*i+1` and the right child in to `2*i+2`.  When doing "down", you keep a collection of todos, that still have to be splitted to reach a leaf. Once you've got only leafs, to go upward (from right to left in the array) to build the decision nodes:

**Update:** A cleaned up version, that also supports the features stored int the branches (type parameter B) and that is more functional/fully pure and that supports sparse trees with a map as suggested by ron.

**Update2-3:** Make economical use of name space for node ids and abstract over type of ids to allow of large trees. Take node ids from Stream.

```
sealed trait DTree[A, B]
case class DTLeaf[A, B](a: A, b: B) extends DTree[A, B]
case class DTBranch[A, B](left: DTree[A, B], right: DTree[A, B], b: B) extends DTree[A, B]

def mktree[A, B, Id](a: A, b: B, split: (A, B) => Option[(A, A, B)], ids: Stream[Id]) = {
  @tailrec
  def goDown(todo: Seq[(A, B, Id)], branches: Seq[(Id, B, Id, Id)], leafs: Map[Id, DTree[A, B]], ids: Stream[Id]): (Seq[(Id, B, Id, Id)], Map[Id, DTree[A, B]]) =
    todo match {
      case Nil => (branches, leafs)
      case (a, b, id) :: rest =>
        split(a, b) match {
          case None =>
            goDown(rest, branches, leafs + (id -> DTLeaf(a, b)), ids)
          case Some((left, right, b2)) =>
            val leftId #:: rightId #:: idRest = ids
            goDown((right, b2, rightId) +: (left, b2, leftId) +: rest, (id, b2, leftId, rightId) +: branches, leafs, idRest)
        }
    }

  @tailrec
  def goUp[A, B](branches: Seq[(Id, B, Id, Id)], nodes: Map[Id, DTree[A, B]]): Map[Id, DTree[A, B]] =
    branches match {
      case Nil => nodes
      case (id, b, leftId, rightId) :: rest =>
        goUp(rest, nodes + (id -> DTBranch(nodes(leftId), nodes(rightId), b)))
    }

  val rootId #:: restIds = ids
  val (branches, leafs) = goDown(Seq((a, b, rootId)), Seq(), Map(), restIds)
  goUp(branches, leafs)(rootId)
}

// try it out

def split(xs: Seq[Int], b: Int) =
  if (xs.size > 1) {
    val (left, right) = xs.splitAt(xs.size / 2)
    Some((left, right, b + 1))
  } else {
    None
  }

val tree = mktree(0 to 1000, 0, split _, Stream.from(0))
println(tree)
```

Comment: What about the fact that each DTBranch needs a "featureIndex"? That makes it quite a bit trickier since to turn all the leaves into branches we need their featureIndex, and then to combine those branches together we need their featureIndexes, and so forth. I think this is the right idea though so I'll play around with it.

Comment: You put the featureIndices into the heap when going down (instead of the None), to have it available for creating the DTBranch, when going up again.

Comment: That's awesome! I'll try it out and mark yours as the answer within the hour.

Comment: Note that storing binary tree as array is only efficient if the tree is balanced. A badly skewed tree would not utilize the array well. Can use an associative array-based variant though.

Comment: I confirmed that this gets the same results as the non-tail-recursive algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: Another note: now that we're using a stream of node id's, we can pack things into an array again and avoid the slowdown of using an associative array, no?